# Google Direction Requested route too long

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-directions-api

We are trying to generate a route into out application. We have source location and destination location. We are using google's direction api to fetch the geocoded_waypoints and plotting it on map.

We have a two location in which google is return error as belod

```
{
   "error_message" : "Requested route too long.",
   "geocoded_waypoints" : [ {}, {} ],
   "routes" : [],
   "status" : "MAX_ROUTE_LENGTH_EXCEEDED"
}
```

This is the request we are trying to fetch

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?mode=WALKING&origin=-33.92514997219349,18.422881477084793&destination=59.55887058784779,150.8106005970545&key=[API](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?mode=WALKING&origin=-33.92514997219349,18.422881477084793&destination=59.55887058784779,150.8106005970545&key=%5BAPI) Key]

The same route is supported on the Google Map

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/cape+town/magadan/@14.4239024,45.6422466,3z/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x1dcc500f8826eed7:0x687fe1fc2828aa87!2m2!1d18.4240553!2d-33.9248685!1m5!1m1!1s0x596984812d524ae9:0x39c94ce7e19c065b!2m2!1d150.8127537!2d59.5594397!3e2

[image: Google Map]

We are trying to get this route. Any help would be appriciated.
Thanks

Comment: The Google Maps APIs and Google Maps are different. [That error](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions?hl=en#StatusCodes) means: "`MAX_ROUTE_LENGTH_EXCEEDED` indicates the requested route is too long and cannot be processed. This error occurs when more complex directions are returned. Try reducing the number of waypoints, turns, or instructions.".  (Why do you need a route to walk 21810km? Not that driving works)

Comment: @geocodezip I am not including any waypoints, just providing the source & destination to the api

Comment: That text is from the documentation.

Comment: @geocodezip thanks mate for stating this but I have already gone through the document but not sure what can I reduce from here as the client wants to get the route I have shown in the image. So I am looking for an answer on how to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tired an embedded map? or the Embed API?

Comment: @geocodezip I wants to use this in web and phone both so I was using the api

Comment: @geocodezip I tried Enbed API and it works good but like I said I also wants to use it in the mobile app and wants to draw some annotations ( marker ) and info-window on that so can't use Embed API